# Unable to set secret_key_base for the production environment in Ruby on Rails 4.1.4 application running on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I am unable to set `secret_key_base` for the production environment in Ruby on Rails 4.1.4 application running on Heroku.

Here are the steps that I've tried to do:

- Run `rake secret` and copy the secret key to the clipboard
- Run `heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE=%SECRET_KEY%`

It returns success and Heroku lists this environment variable in the dashboard on the site, but the application still thinks that the secret key was not provided:

> Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value
>   in `config/secrets.yml`

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `config/secrets.yml` to version control and deploy again. You might need to remove a line from `.gitignore` so that you can commit the file.

`.gitignore` Github created for my Rails application included `config/secrets.yml`

---

**OR**

Follow this steps:

1. $ `heroku config` (run this command in your terminal)
2. Copy value from `SECRET_KEY_BASE`
3. paste value to `secrets.yml` file in place of `<%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>` (without any quote)

**e.g**

```
production:
  secret_key_base: b1de60dd9e00816d0569c5ce3f8dbaa3c8ea4a7606120dc66cXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

4. re-deploy

**Note:** Actually this is not safe but in-case you just wanted to run your app temporary in production mode for testing or in emergency condition

I hope it works for you...

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks a lot! But why "config/secrets.yml" file is included to the .gitignore by default? And about your second version -- I read that it's unsafe to keep secret key base for the production environment. Why did you recommend it?

Comment: @FrozenHeart : I had face the same issue like you and I was just wanted to run the app on production so I tried this and worked. But after that I came to know about the first option and made changes...I happy to know that I can help you somehow..by default it puts in gitignore to avoid untracked files

Comment: I mean why they decided to place it in .gitignore file?

Answer (score 0):

What is in your `config/secrets.yml`? For production it should contain the lines:

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Comment: Yes, but it also have "<%=" and "%>" around the ENV

Comment: Maybe this is recognized by Heroku as config var and not the environment var? If so, what should I do?